# How do I rename a file on Android in-app located in the shared folders

Tags: android

Is it possible to silently (without popups) rename files on Android located in the Files app using my own app? I cannot have MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission as Google Play always rejects it.

I've tried so many examples of content resolver, SAF but none seem to work.

Comment: If the file is not created by your app, then no.

Comment: `.. files on Android located in the Files app ` What do you mean? You cannot store files in apps to begin with. So tell storage location of files instead.

Comment: `located in the Files app ` ????

Comment: regarding the Files app, I only meant located in the Internal Storage of the device.

Comment: `.. on Android located in the Files app using ... ` Then edit your post. Third time i ask.

Comment: Further you speak about shared folders and internal; storage. We heve no idea what you mean by that. Instead tell full paths. (in your post, not as comments).  Or use the terminology for us programmers. You can name the functions.

Comment: `...Android in-app located....` ?????????? Please write de decnet post.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile?hl=en#renameTo(java.lang.String)